# i need to pull the data from the highest id instead of the lowest in this sql command?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  DEBTOR_ID, 
        LEFT(NAME1, 30) AS NAME1, 
        SSN1, 
        DOB1, 
        DL1, 
        PRIORITY, 
        NEXT_CONTACT_DATE, 
        NEXT_CONTACT_TIME, 
        STATUS_CODE, 
        SCORE, 
        ASSIGN_ID 
FROM    DM.DBTR 
WHERE   STATUS_CODE = 110 
AND     ASSIGN_ID = '001'
ORDER BY DBTR.DEBTOR_id
```

Comment: Do you mean that rather than `ASSIGN_ID='001'` you need to pick whatever has the largest `ASSIGN_ID` for that group (would that be the `debtor_id`?)

Comment: Do you mean to list the IDs in descending order? In that case you would just add "desc" to your order by clause like: `ORDER BY DBTR.DEBTOR_id DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean order by descending order, just use

```
ORDER BY DBTR.DEBTOR_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just order your data in descending order by using the `desc` keyword:

```
SELECT   DEBTOR_ID, LEFT(NAME1, 30) AS NAME1, SSN1, DOB1, DL1,
         PRIORITY,
         NEXT_CONTACT_DATE, NEXT_CONTACT_TIME, STATUS_CODE, SCORE,
         ASSIGN_ID 
FROM     DM.DBTR 
WHERE    STATUS_CODE = 110 AND ASSIGN_ID = '001'
ORDER BY DBTR.DEBTOR_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are talking about the ASSIGN_ID ? if so you can use [IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx). So it would be something like

```
IDENT_CURRENT('ASSIGN')
```

where ASSIGN is the table name that relates to ASSIGN_ID

You can also

```
ORDER BY ASSIGN_ID DESC
```